# Text not aligning center, left

Tags: css

Good Day

I am having a bad CSS day. I have 3-column div (horizontal, thats why I am using the float), but I want to align my text in the center, but to the left of the containing column div.

HTML:

```
 <div id="footer">
        <div class="footerColumn">
            <ul>
                <li><a>Contact Us</a></li>
                <li><a>Home</a></li>
                <li><a>Emergency Numbers</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="footerColumn">
            <ul>
                <li><a>Support</a></li>
                <li><a>Privacy Policy</a></li>
                <li><a>Terms of Use</a></li>
                <li><a>Careers</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="footerColumn">
            <ul>
                <li><p><a>login</a></p></li>
                <li><a>Sign Up</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div style="clear: both;"></div>

 </div>
```

CSS:

```
#footer {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px;
    background: url('/images/bg2.png') repeat-x center;

    border-top: 6px solid #f3911f;
    background: #1b1d21;
}
    #footer div.footerColumn {
        position: relative;
        float: left;
        width: 33%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        text-align: justify;
    }
    #footer div.footerColumn ul li {

    }
    #footer ul li a{
        color: #fff;           
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
        text-decoration: none;
        cursor: pointer;       
    }
    #footer div.disclaimer {
        color: #ccc;
        font-family: verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 12px;

    }
```

SEE MY [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/DvXzB/46/)

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why you are unable to center the `<ul>` element in your design is because the `<li>` elements are stretching the parent `<ul>` width to 100%, therefore using `margin: 0 auto` will not work.

Instead, I suggest that you use `display: inline-block` for your `<ul>` - allowing it to ONLY stretch as far as the width of inner contents (the child `<li>` elements), and not to the 100% width of the containing element.

As for the children `<li>`, you can set them to display as a block element, float them to the left and then clear the left float, therefore forcing each floated element to start on a new line (because you clear the left float for every element).

Simply implement the style suggested as follow:

```
#footer ul {
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#footer ul li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    clear: left;
}
#footer ul li a{
    color: #fff;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;       
}
```

Check the fiddle here ;) http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/DvXzB/48/

Comment: You're welcome, @DavidVanStaden. However, inline-block may not work properly in older versions of IE... you've been warned :P

Answer (score 0):

Use `text-align:center` in your footerColumn divs.

```
   #footer div.footerColumn {
        position: relative;
        float: left;
        width: 33%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        text-align: center;
    }
```

Comment: nope, just centers the text in the center, and not to the left...If you understand what I mean...

Answer (score 0):

```
#footer div.footerColumn {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 33%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center; /*new here*/
}
#footer div.footerColumn ul {
float: left; /*new here*/
}
```